# Angular2 events delegate

Tags: angular

in clear Javascript i can delegate events, to decrease number of necessary functions handling events to one, for the entire node set. For example:

```
<div id="click-wrap">
  <button>Click me, nr 1</button>
  <button>Click me, nr 2</button>
  <button>Click me, nr 3</button>
</div>
```

How to get similar effect in angular2? In detail I want to remove add class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add a directive to the `<div id="click-wrap">` that will bind to the `click` event and read `event.target`:

```
@Directive({selector: '[custom]')
export class CustomDirective {
   @HostListener('click') clicked($event) {
      console.log($event.target); // this will be a child button
   }
}

<div id="click-wrap" custom>
```

Comment: The event.target will be one of the buttons, but what if the button is in an ngFor loop and you want to target the data that it represents?

Comment: @LarsGyrupBrinkNielsen, what is `data that is represents`?

Comment: Let's take a simple example. We're ngFor-looping through an array of strings, rendering a button for each string. I want a delegated click handler that passes the string that was enumerated when the button was rendered and the button text does not include this text.

Comment: @LarsGyrupBrinkNielsen, can you please create a separate question with all the details and link it here?

Answer (score 0):

From [LearnAngular2.com](http://learnangular2.com/events/)

```
@Component(...)
class MyComponent {
  clicked(event) {
    // This gives you the event object
    // You can do things like any normal event such as view the target
    console.log(event.target);
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="click-wrap" (click)="clicked($event)">
  <button>Click me, nr 1</button>
  <button>Click me, nr 2</button>
  <button>Click me, nr 3</button>
</div>
```